# how to transfer contacts from a micro sim to a mini sim if the screen is broken and not getting comands?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, nexus-4

how to transfer my contacts from a micro sim to a mini sim if my phone screen is broken and is not getting my commands neither? from a galaxy s 2 to a nexus

Comment: sorry i get the confise the sim with sd. the question is about sim cards

Comment: If your screen is broken, and doesn't take any input, I guess you either need the device to be repaired (which changes the pre-condition of your question), or to get a new device (which does the same). In both cases, you've got a working device and then proceed as normal. I guess there are adapters available for the cards.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that the contacts from your old phone were actually stored on your SIM card. That's not the default for most Android phones, which store contacts in the device storage, or online in your Google account.

1. Get a SIM card adapter.
2. Take the card out of your old phone.
3. Put the card in the adapter.
4. Put the card+adapter into your new phone.
5. Transfer the contacts from the card onto the phone's memory. You can do this by editing the contacts one by one in the Contacts app, or you can find an app to import contacts from the SIM card in one operation.

Now the contacts are on your new phone, and you can replace the usual SIM card in that phone. If your new phone is SIM-locked to a different carrier, you can ask a friend and borrow their phone.

Alternativaly, you can buy a USB SIM card reader. That way, when you have the SIM card in the adapter, you can plug that into your PC and use the software that comes with the reader to save the contacts onto your PC. You can then import them into your new phone, or into your Google account.